# How to install drivers for NVIDIA (NVS 5200m) for Dell Latitude E6430 laptop in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, graphics, dell, intel-graphics

I have a new Dell's laptop E6430 with two VGAs (the Intel and nVidia).

I tried to download the file from the official site of nVidia but it caused the system to crash. I'm now on a new fresh system.

I need detailed instruction for safely installing the driver and also how to switch between the two cards.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be identical/very similar with this one: [How can drivers for Nvidia graphics cards be installed on Ubuntu 13.04 without messing up the OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310311/how-can-drivers-for-nvidia-graphics-cards-be-installed-on-ubuntu-13-04-without-m)

I think the answer I've wrote there might apply in your case as well.

Good luck and let us know what happens!