# Ubuntu won't login after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04

yesterday i installed ubuntu 14.04 without any problems. I want to use my nvidia drivers instead of the integrated intel graphics so I tried to use the driver checker provided by ubuntu, the problem with this is that ubuntu gets internal errors.

The next problem is that when I install nvidia drivers by using the `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` ubuntu won't login to the computer. Note that I can start the computer and I get to the login screen but after entering the password the only thing that happens is that I can see my background image just like the desktop is loading. By using CTRL+ ALT + F1 I removed the nvidia drivers and the ubuntu worked again.

How can I get the nvidia drivers to work? and what could I do about the internal error message?

Specs:

- ASUS K53S
- intel core i5 (2.6 GHz)
- Nvidia GT 630M 2GB
- 4GB Ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the safest way is to use the additional drivers that are provided by Ubuntu

in the dash write " additional drivers"

in my laptop i used the proprietary, tested and this is working fine

[image]

you may refer also to this topic for more info

[How can drivers for Nvidia graphics cards be installed on Ubuntu 13.04 without messing up the OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310311/how-can-drivers-for-nvidia-graphics-cards-be-installed-on-ubuntu-13-04-without-m)

Comment: I want to use your suggestion but as i said before ubuntu gets internal errors when searching for drivers when using "Additional drivers".

Comment: I would also prefere to fix the internal error message if that is possible before i install any drivers. It might be harmless but if someone know how to fix it i would try that solution before installing any drivers at all...

Comment: Well after almost a week of double checking so that i dont make things wors i decided to try Bumblebee once again (last time i failed horrible on 12.04). Anyway it worked great =D thanks alot. Even though i still get errors when i try to update my hardware =[

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on a notebook with a 540M (w/ Optimus). Using the proprietary drivers (tested or updates) in "Additional drivers" doesn't work. The only way to get to the unity greeter is to purge nvidia and use Nouveau.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1310551

Comment: @v2r This does include the essential part of the answer: "The only way to get to the unity greeter is to purge nvidia and use Nouveau."

Comment: My mistake! Thanks for pointing it out Eliah Kagan. I deleted my previous comment for good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem in a Toshiba with GeForce 350M and I posted my [solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526571/apt-get-ends-up-with-errors-after-nvidia-331-installation/560515#560515). Try it and see if it works.