# Ubuntu does not log in after installing nvida driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 14.04

after installing 14.04 on my plain notebook (ThinkPad L430 with NVS5400M Graphic-Card) I also wanted to install the nvidia drivers. I did this via the GUI in the System administration.  (as decribed here [Ubuntu won't login after installing nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452537/ubuntu-wont-login-after-installing-nvidia-drivers) ) I tried version 331.38 as well as 304.117.
Unfortunately I was not able to log on the unity any more after rebooting the system. It remained just purple. 
So I went to the shell and de-installed the nvidia driver manually. After that everything was fine again.
But the problem is, that the computer is quite slow without the drivers and has micro-freezes from time to time.

Has anybody an idea, how I can find out what causes the error? Or has anybody had a similar problem? 
Or any idea how I can install the driver?

Comment: What version of the driver was installed by the GUI?

Comment: I updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the NVidia 319.60 driver.  Try that one.  As you have noticed, the wrong driver just doesn't work.  Usually selecting the "current" or "current updates" will give you a working driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe a stupid question: But is `sudo apt-get install nvidia-319-update` the right command to install the version? Because that's what I did. Now i can log in, but the system is unfortunately freezing even more and heavier.

Comment: My fault, I forgot to configure!