# apt-get ends up with errors after nvidia 331 installation

Tags: 14.04, apt, nvidia, python, utf-8

I recently installed `nvidia-331` driver via `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` tab.

Now when I use:

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove <package>
```

`apt-get` ends up with following errors:

```
lyn@antares:~$ sudo apt-get install hexedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hexedit
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 88.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package hexedit.
(Reading database ... 226032 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../hexedit_1.2.13-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking hexedit (1.2.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-331 (331.89-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.2) ...
INFO:Enable nvidia-331
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 65, in <module>
    operation_status = main(options)
  File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 44, in main
    quirks = Quirks.quirkapplier.QuirkChecker(options.package_enable, path=quirks_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkapplier.py", line 38, in __init__
self._system_info = self.get_system_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkapplier.py", line 64, in get_system_info
return quirk_info.get_dmi_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkinfo.py", line 46, in get_dmi_info
'class', 'dmi', 'id', item)).read().strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-331 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up hexedit (1.2.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-331
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already tried to remove nvidia drivers using [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) however `apt-get` still shows almost the same error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: what is your "sudo apt-get update" giving?Is this showing any error messages?

Comment: @saptarshinag no, it doesn't

Comment: Remove the nvidia-331 then install the current driver version by "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current"

Comment: @saptarshinag both "sudo apt-get remove nvidia-331" and "sudo-apt-get install nvidia-current" starts and fails (with the same errors I posted above). Is there a proper way to uninstall a driver without apt-get ?

Comment: see this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153208/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This worked for me :)**

Make a backup and edit the file:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/quirks-handler /usr/bin/quirks-handler.bak
sudo gedit /usr/bin/quirks-handler
```

replace the contents with the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Purge nvidia-331:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-331
```

It will complete successfully, and then you can restore the backup:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/quirks-handler.bak /usr/bin/quirks-handler
```

Comment: Well... that worked for me too but then `Unity` crashed after a while. Using `Ctrl+Alt+F1` I've managed to install `nvidia-340` driver. Doing so I recovered `Unity` but `apt-get` fails again.

Comment: You must not have nvidia drivers from PPA. Keep the latest drivers from the repository. Do the trick again to remove 340 and install 331 which is part of ubuntu 14.10 right now.

Comment: Worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

A brutally way to remove the problem is the following

1. edit the file /var/lib/dpkg/info/package-name.postrm; in this case
   it should be  `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-331.postrm`
2. adds exit 0 after the line `#!bin/sh` and save.
3. run "sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-331". It should end without errors.
4. make sure to delete the previously added line from the file (so again `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/package-name.postrm`, remove the line and save).
5. before trying anything else, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and check that it returns without errors.

Comment: on step 3 it ends with errors http://pastebin.com/nhak1W4D but thanks anyway

Comment: try this: `dkms remove -m X -v Y --all`. You have to replace X and Y with your current module and version. To do this, after typing `-m nv` press two times the tab button to see what it displays. Then do the same with Y.
E.G. for me it is `dkms remove -m nvidia-304 -v 304.117 --all`

Comment: I pressed the tab button and it suggested me nothing. I mean, `nv[tab][tab]` doesn't turn into `nvidia-331`. Also `nvidia-settings` doesn't list any of nvidia drivers.

Comment: can you post again the output of `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` and `apt-get upgrade -f`?

Comment: `grep:` http://pastebin.com/BkhMwKLj `upgrade:` http://pastebin.com/DfQd6wez

Comment: try this:
  1. logout from your graphic session
  2. press CTRL+ALT+F1 to login from tty and insert your user and password 
  3. run `apt-get purge nvidia*`
  4. logout and restart the system
  5. see if something has changed running again the previous commands (grep and upgrade)

Comment: also, this is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1320868

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to purge `nvidia-current`, `autoremove`, restart, install `cairo-dock` then go to software updates and select the nvidia 331 from additional drivers (it took much more time than installing from `cli`), restart. Then from terminal install `CCSM` and activate the unity plug-in.

Now in commands what I think is the minimum to solve the issue:

1. Before login (because lightdm shows the login) type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. From the `CLI` type `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock`
3. Now type`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
4. Go back to the login typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
5. select `cairo` as your shell (click in the Ubuntu icon) and login as normal
6. From the application menu in Cairo go to **system tools->preferences->CompizConfig Settings Manager**
7. Click OK in the warning dialog
8. Click over desktop button in the left panel.
9. Push the Ubuntu Unity Plugin button in the right panel
10. Check the check box in the left panel to activate Ubuntu Unity Plugin
11. Activate everything that is needed in order to get Unity back
12. Voilá Unity is again working as before

I hope those steps make sense. the first explanation was a super fast story telling of what I had to do, so if the detailed minimum steps doesn't work for you then follow the exactly path I had to do

1. Don't login type<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, so you go to the `CLI`
2. login and then type `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock`
3. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`  and confirm
4. Now type `sudo apt-get autoremove`  and confirm
5. `sudo reboot`
6. Now login from `lightDM` (graphically) as usual but selecting the `cairo` shell from the Ubuntu icon
7. If the GUI appears good jump to step 11; otherwise
8. Go back to CLI typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
9. type cairo-dock (I hope it starts correctly in your GUI; otherwise, you have to specify the DISPLAY before -gurus, please help-)
10. Return to GUI typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
11. From the applications menu in Cairo go to System Tools->Software Updates
12. when it finished to update push the configuration button and go to the last tab (additional drivers)
13. Other way is to go to **System Tools->Preferences->Additional Drivers**
14. Select the best (tested) Nvidia driver and apply changes
15. Restart using Cairo icon for that
16. Then login again and install `compizconfig-settings-manager` **using System tools->Administration->Ubuntu Software Center**
17. Continue from step 6 of the minimum steps (the previous list)

I hope this makes sense and work for you as it worked for me.