# Ubuntu 14.10 and Nvidia 331 problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm not and old ubuntu user so I'm here to question a problem.
Yesterday I updated the Nvidia driver to 331 (as the reccomended updates say) and after restart I had a beatiful gift: the screen is similar to default (eg 800x600) and I don't have menu or icons desktop... Nothing, just the cursor. I tried to open with keyboard the Terminal but nothing happens. I tried to restore filesystems but didn't work... I really don't know what to do. As I read on other discussions, don't say me "give me logs" or something like that because I can't access my ubuntu desktop.

EDIT: I tried deleting Nvidia drivers and reinstalling, nothing changed
Restarting often the computer brought the desktop back but on 800x600 and there wasn't the left menu and icons weren't all. Indeed I tried to change resoluton but there was jut 800x600. I tried to install boot-repair but I don't have a GUI to launch it. I don't know what to do!

---

So I did: reinstall unity and ubuntu desktop and reboot but nothing works. I can only access the first login screen (password) and after that I only see desktop and cursor.
I really don't know what's the problem. By the way I can access terminal with ctrl alt f1 so if you need something just say me.

Comment: Try to check one thing. open the terminal and put in: `cd /etc/X11` then write `dir` and hit enter. How many `xorg.conf`files do you see? Probably the Nvidia update left a empty xorg.conf file.

Comment: I answered this [issue here][1], so try JQL's solution and see


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/526571/apt-get-ends-up-with-errors-after-nvidia-331-installation/560515#560515

Answer (score 2):

This is related to a version conflict with the kernel module. I am not sure why this happens.

/var/log/kern.log:

> API mismatch: the client has the version 331.113, but this kernel module has the version 331.89.

Try this:

```
Ctrl+Alt+F2
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo reboot
```

Back in a desktop (I wish I knew a better procedure for this/why it worked):

```
Ctrl+Alt+F2
$ DISPLAY=:0 unity
Ctrl+Alt+F7
Right Click Desktop -> Open In terminal
$ dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
$ unity
```

There should now be a unity interface (but slow as molasses)

```
Reboot
```

Back in unity:

```
Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> 331.113 updates
Apply & Wait & Wait & Wait
Reboot... (When done)
```

Victory!

Comment: Thanks big time!  `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` seemed to have solved everything for me, though I'm not sure I had the exact same problem.